# How to rewrite this javascript code using only jQuery instead

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner at jQuery, so I had a friend help me write some script for an effect I was having trouble with. Problem, is he is pretty much only familiar with Javascript and doesn't know how to translate this same script into jQuery. Is there a way to write this same code into jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //milliseconds - change this value to modify the delay between 
    //one text animation and the other
    var delay = 1000;    

    //milliseconds - change this value to modify the single text
    //animation speed   
    var timing = 2000; 
    animateText('creative_div', timing);

    //setTimeout allow to call the function animateText after a 
    //certain delay (declared above)
    setTimeout("animateText('motivated_div'," + timing + ");", delay);
    setTimeout("animateText('skilled_div'," + timing + ");", delay * 2);

});

function animateText(divElement, timing) {

    //$(divElement).style="visibility: visible";
    document.getElementById(divElement).style.visibility = "visible";
    $('#'+divElement).effect('drop', 
                        { 
                            direction:"up", 
                            mode:"show", 
                            distance:"400" 
                        }, 
                        timing);
}
```

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like homework. Also use the code sample function on your javascript code.

Comment: Also, you're already using jQuery all over the place.

Comment: How do you write jquery without javascript?

Comment: @Jason - Really? Converting plain JavaScript to jQuery sounds like homework to you? What in the world are they teaching in CS departments these days?

Comment: @Iwburk - How do you know everyone who uses Stack goes to University? ;)

Comment: My college doesn't teach JavaScript at all (and it's the largest CS college in my country).

Comment: Really, there is no advantage to "translating" JavaScript such as this to "jQuery" (as if jQuery is a language by itself). All that jQuery will do is bounce the code around a million different functions to ultimately do no more than what your friend wrote. The motto of jQuery is "write less, do more". In this instance, use of jQuery would be an example of "write the same, achieve nothing more, don't understand what's happening and bounce your code through a million different functions for no good reason".

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
function animateText(id, t) {
    $('#' + id)
        .css('visibility', 'visible')
        .effect('drop', {direction: 'up', mode: 'show', distance: '400'}, t);
}  

$(function() {    
    var delay = 1000,
        timing = 2000,
        ids = ['creative_div', 'motivated_div', 'skilled_div'];

    $.each(ids, function(i, id) {
        setTimeout(function() { animateText(id, timing); }, delay * i);    
    });
});
```

---

Btw, you can use a regular for loop instead of $.each:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { animateText(ids[i], timing); }, delay * i);
}
```

A regular loop preforms slightly faster, but is also slightly more ugly.

Comment: beauty is in the eye of the beholder! It could be written as a while loop: `var i = ids.length;while(i--) {...}`.

Comment: @RobG Yes, poor choice of words from my side. A for-loop is more low-level which can be considered a disadvantage compared to jQuery's method.

Comment: Hi Sime, Thanks so much. Do you know if there is a book or site for absolute beginners to "explain" what certain symbols in the syntax mean? I am so new to this, that I am not sure what * , t and i and other symbols signify. S

Comment: @Sue `*` is the multiplication operator. `t` is just the name I've given to the second argument of the `animateText` function. I'm calling this function like so: `animateText(id, timing);` - therefore, the value 2000 is passed into `animateText` as the second argument. `i` is the first argument of the `$.each` callback. Read about `$.each` function [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).